# How can I run LaTeX from Sublimetext 2?

Tags: compiling, editors, ide

Actually, I have read the similar issues that are asked here. But still I can not find a solution for my case. I loaded Latextools plugin, and I installed Sumatra pdf viewer. Even though I added to the path sumatra pdf. I am getting the same error which is:

```
Cannot launch Viewer. Make sure it is on your PATH.
```

What should I do to fix this problem to run my .tex files from Sublimetext 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

When I looked to fix this problem, I ve encountered with a solution by chance. I changed my viewPDF.py file, as shown in the following link:

[viewPDF.py](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/viewPDF.py)

And now, it is working..

Comment: Nice. Will you be able to provide a patch for windows also, the way I read the code it does not provide one (I have not tried it).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I am running sublimetext 2 on windows 7.

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a try. sublimetext is a great editor.

Comment: The link is dead now, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

For windows put the complete path of sumatra pdf viewer in `viewpdf.py` file. For example in my case I put,

```
elif s == "Windows":
            viewercmd = ["C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe", "-reuse-instance"]
```

I am using xp.